# Drawing on image with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add a timestamp on an image that is being loaded. So I have for now the following code to do this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src  = e.target.result;
  imageObj.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0,0);
    context.font = "40pt Calibri";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);

    console.log(e.target.result);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    category.Pictures.push({offlineFoto: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), FileNameOnDevice: guid});
  };

    leftToProcess--;
    if (leftToProcess == 0) {
        $scope.loadingCat = false;
        $scope.loadingSubCat = false;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

When I check the console.log of `e.target.result` i get the base64 of the correct image, but when i check the log of the `canvas.toDataURL()` it contains the same image.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `canvas.width = this.width;` after the `context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);` clear the whole canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the canvas' width or height, even the value is the same, it empty the entire canvas, you need to move them before you draw. [Spec:canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#concept-canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions).

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src  = e.target.result;
  imageObj.onload = function(){
    //
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    // Move them before drawing anything.
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0,0);
    context.font = "40pt Calibri";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);
    console.log(e.target.result);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    category.Pictures.push({offlineFoto: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), FileNameOnDevice: guid});
  };

    leftToProcess--;
    if (leftToProcess == 0) {
        $scope.loadingCat = false;
        $scope.loadingSubCat = false;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

And there's other that would make your text not visible, the color of the position you put the text, the `baseline`, these may made the text written but not visible.

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

// Canvas cleared
cv.width = 300;
cv.height = 100;

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100); // Fill half with black


ctx.font = "40pt Calibri";
ctx.fillText('1', 20, 20); // black alphabetic, so can't be seen

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillText("2", 135, 20); // red alphabetic. So some part is clipped.

ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText('3', 135, 20); // red top. All in region.
```

```html
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Comment: yep that fixes the black image, but now it contains my original image

Comment: ...and `toDataURL` is entirely black because jpeg cannot handle transparent pixels. Cleared canvas pixels ==  fully transparent pixels == rgba(0,0,0,0). These get converted by jpeg to rgba(0,0,0,255) so they end up fully black.

Comment: You may also need to specify `context.fillStyle` first.

Comment: @Kiwi would you post the origin image here so we can see what would be the result after drawing text on the image.

Comment: Your fillStyle was the answer :)